# How to get all Accent Color Theme and Save Color new in Windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to get all Accent Color and display ListPicker Control? After I change Accent Color and Save, Help me?

Comment: Can you explain the context in how you want to use it?

Comment: I want to app can change the accent color when app running!

Answer (score 0):

You have all the ressouces for theme colors [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402557%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Whenanewthemeisselected).

You have an access at all the theme colors specified by the user (when you choose your theme in the settings) for your application.

BUT it's not possible to change the User Ui theme with Your Application... and even less to create.

This features has been requested by the developer but refused... ([you can read the request features here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1719389-can-set-custom-theme))

For user change the UI theme in your application, the only method is to redirect user to the settings panel...